# Cannot echo strings with "" , '' and /n from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried to show a description from the YouTube API to `p` element but it's not working. I think the problem is with the quotes, single quote and new line; ie. `""` , `''`  and `\n`.

This is the description text:

> Another contestant attempts to overcome 'Head Case'! Will Daniel be able to "master" his fear of the unknown and be able to carry on singing?\n\nSubscribe for more awesome clips!\n\nSubscribe now!

```php
$description = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["description"];
echo "<script>$('.pClass:nth-of-type(4)').text($description);</script>";
```

Note that it's working like this: `$('.pClass:nth-of-type(4)').text('test');`, but it's not working when read from the API.

Comment: you shouldn't mix PHP and JS like this - they execute differently and is harder to maintain. Just use ajax to send back-and-forth php data

Comment: but I want to set php variable in element using javascript or jquery do you have good way to that without echo ?

Comment: yeah .. ajax xD

Comment: There's little reason to make an entirely new AJAX request just to fetch a value that your page already has.  But one thing you do need to do is elaborate on what "not working" means.  What client-side code is emitting to the browser by this server-side code?  In what way does it fail?  Surely the lack of quotes in the client-side code is a problem, but what other problems might there also be?  Examine the code in your browser and find out.

Comment: Can you give us example what is value of `$description`

Answer (score 3):

You're outputting data to JavaScript, so you need to escape it in a way that will be safe for JavaScript to consume. Since JSON is a subset of JavaScript, you can use `json_encode()` for this purpose.

You should also avoid outputting JS in a double-quoted string; you can have problems with JS values being interpreted as PHP variables.

```
<?php
$description = json_encode($vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["description"]);
?>

<script>
    $('.pClass:nth-of-type(4)').text(<?=$description?>);
</script>
```